# Sum of decimal digits in java

Tags: java, sum, double, decimal

How to find out sum of decimal digits in java.I have tried the normal way as we do for int values,but the sum is for just before precision digits and for after precision digits the output is not clear.I also tried searching for it but no answers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        double rem;
        double sum = 0.0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a 5 digit decimal number:");

        double num = sc.nextDouble();

        while(num > 0) {

            rem = num % 10;
            sum = sum + rem;
            num = num / 10;

        }
        System.out.println("Sum of digits = "+sum);
    }
```

*Expected Output:*

Enter a num: 12.12

Sum: 6.0

*Output I am getting:*

Enter a num: 12.12

Sum: 3.4666666666666655

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your try code.

Comment: use double  , instead of int

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala I have added my code please check

Comment: @NarayanParvatikar I used it

Comment: Please add your inputs and expected output also

Comment: Do you mean something like 12345 or 22222 by _5 digit decimal number_? Or can it also contain floating points like, 1.2345, 0.2222

Comment: @NarayanP I have added them,check it

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala no, but something like this 12.123 or 123.12

Comment: Are you sure you need to accept a floating point number (with a decimal point in it)? An integer like 98765 is a 5 digit decimal number too, and much easier to handle. “Decimal” just refers to the number being in the base 10 number system (as opposed to binary or hexadecimal, for example).

Comment: What you're trying doesn't work because decimals behave different in your algorithm than integers. `203.56 % 10` is already `3.56`, not `3`. `203.56 / 10` is `20.356` and you're not cutting off any digits.
To make your algorithm work, you could multiply the number so you don't have any digits after the decimal point, and then `Math.floor` between each step. Or use a different algorithm altogether.

Comment: @OleV.V. I don't know that integer like this 12345 is also a decimal number. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the digits one by one and add them to the sum. Try this,

```
int sum = 0;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a 5 digit decimal number:");

char[] s = sc.next().toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    try {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(s[i] + "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

System.out.println("Sum of digits = " + sum);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use exception handling then you should try this-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 double sum = 0.0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a 5 digit decimal number:");
        double num = sc.nextDouble();

        String number = String.valueOf(num);
        for (char c : number.toCharArray()) {
                if(c!='.')
                    sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));

        }
        System.out.println("Sum of digits = " + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here a simple way to accomplish it in Java 8+ (explanation in comments):

```
class Main{
  public static void main(String[] a){
    java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.nextLine();               // Get the input-decimal as String
    int sumOfDigits = input.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "") // Remove all non-digits from the input-String
                           .chars()                  // Convert it to a stream of characters
                           .map(c -> c-48)           // Convert the character to a digit
                           .sum();                   // Sum everything together
    System.out.println("Sum of digits = "+sumOfDigits);
  }
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##fVBLSwMxEL73Vww5ZdENtij4QEHQm@Jhj6XCNJvWrMnskkdVpL99zaZ7EEo3lyH5npMGd1g29WffS4Pewytq@p0BdHFttAQfMKSxa3UNNkG8Ck7TdrkCLAYaQJMMRAzaiEoikXLgx3kPpL6OcV79@KCs0FTcZYfx3sYgumQeOHumkPQIV1DrrQ5QK6ktGqBo18rdAhuVB3luBJq6GFLmmC5IfYcXTYqfSDHEs2SE0wv4aN82T0OiT0YZFU51BqV6NIaz5ftFebNi54wVWXPiCPmBzvNpjsWOy/JBlpfX08RUamIFVkUL7ebwT0NrdvZvi6zbz/Z9P1@I@eIP)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double sum = 0.0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a 5 digit decimal number:");
    double num = sc.nextDouble();

    String number = String.valueOf(num);
    for (char c : number.toCharArray()) {
        try {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // ignore the . 
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of digits = " + sum);
}
```

Comment: Rather than reading into a double and converting into a string, I suggest you read into a string from the outset. Then you’re sure no double imprecision comes in the way. If you want the validation, you can also try converting the string to a double for that purpose only.